# Adding new fields to a Bond schema

Tags: bond

Suppose I had serialized a given schema `A`, and then updated it to schema `A'` by adding a new nullable field `X` to it. Could I deserialize objects serialized using schema `A` with schema `A'`? After deserialization, will the new field have value `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on whether your field is marked "required" or not (see [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html#requiredattribute)))

- If marked required, deserialization will fail.
- If not required, you can deserialize objects with schema `A'` from a payload that was generated by schema `A` and the field `X` will be null.

See also this [SO question on schema evolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860787/microsoft-bond-schema-evolution-best-practices?rq=1), and the [section in the Bond documentation.](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html#schema-evolution)