# Are Bond field names used in deserialization?

Tags: bond

Suppose I serialized a given Bond struct with a single field:

```
struct NameBond
{
    1: string name;
}
```

And then I renamed the field in the .bond file (without changing its ordinal):

```
struct NameBond
{
    1: string displayName;
}
```

Would I still be able to deserialize it?

What about the name of the struct? (`NameBond` in the example.)

Would changing that prevent me from deserializing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on which protocol you are using.

- Your change will cause no problems in the `CompactBinary` serializer.
- It may cause trouble with other protocols.

You may want to consult the [Bond schema evolution guide](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cs.html#schema-evolution), where it says:

> Caution should be used when changing or reusing field names as this could break text-based protocols like SimpleJsonProtocol

See also [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860787/microsoft-bond-schema-evolution-best-practices).